# I am trying to get both keys from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I am trying to print out a message when the key was found but also the corresponding value of the other key . This is what I have so far

```
l = [{'a': "dog", 'b': "black"}, {'a': "cat", 'b': "yellow"}, {'a': "bird", 'b': "blue"}] 

def search(name, value): 
    for k in list: 
        if k['brand'] == name: 
            print("The dog was found with color" + str(k['age'] == value)) 
search('dog','')
```

and I am trying the output to be that

```
The dog was found and the color is black.
```

Comment: This is what I got so far :

Comment: def search(name, value):
    for k in list:
        if k['brand'] == name:
         print("The dog was found with color" + str(k['age'] == value))

search('dog','')

Comment: Please delete these comments and put them in the question.

Comment: It print that the dog was found but with value False ... how can I rephrase so it will print the value of b also ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There are too many undefined variable, so the code makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [{'a': "dog", 'b': "black"}, {'a': "cat", 'b': "yellow"}, {'a': "bird", 'b': "blue"}]

def search_dict(l, name, key='b'):
    for dic in l:
        if name in dic.values():
            print(f"{name} was found with color {dic[key]}")

search_dict(l, 'dog')
>>> dog was found with color black
```

So what happens here:

1. First a list with dictionaries is created (`l`)
2. The function gets the list with dictionaries, a name to look for in the values of each dictionary and a key for the color of the dictionary, default `key='b'`. If `name` is in one of the values of the dictionary then it prints that is was found with a given color, based on the `key='b'`.
3. The function returns `None`, it only prints what is found.

Why the key input:

```
l = [{'animal': 'dog', 'color':'brown'}, {'animal': 'dog', 'color':'red'},{'animal': 'cat', 'color':'brown'}]

search_dict(l, name='dog', key='color')
>>> dog was found with color brown
>>> dog was found with color red
```

Comment: No that is only true if `name` is the `key` (in the first example `a`) but `name` is one of the values in the dictionary.

Comment: Oh yeah, i though it was the key, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there is an entry with both 'animal' and 'color' I think that this piece of code should work:

```py
l = [{'a': "dog", 'b': "black"}, {'a': "cat", 'b': "yellow"}, {'a': "bird", 'b': "blue"}] 

def search(animal, color): 
    for k in l: 
        if k['a'] == animal and k['b'] == color: 
            print("The {a} was found with color {b}".format(**k)) 

search('dog', 'black')
```

gives you:

```
The dog was found with color black
```

You just need to cycle through the list and check that entries for 'a' and for 'b' are as requested.

Personally I'd use different names instead of just 'a' and 'b', like:

```
l = [{'animal': "dog", 'color': "black"}, {'animal': "cat", 'color': "yellow"}, {'animal': "bird", 'color': "blue"}]
```

but it depends on your requirements...

Comment: @Andy, please vote my question if you find it useful. Thanks!